# detect previous character state

Tags: superscripts

I am using the following tex-file:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
foo\footnote{test.}\footnote{test2}
\end{document}
```

And the result is two adjacent superscript numbers: [image]

I want to add a comma between the two numbers. Something in the line of

```
if (supercript number as the last char) print ,
```

Is there a general way to achieve that, not limited to the footnote example?

Comment: I am looking for the way to do it, not necessarily footnotes. I will have a look into `footmisc` to find the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no control possible on what has already been set; however this can be done by redefining suitably `\footnote`:

```
\makeatletter
\let\kernel@footnote\footnote
\renewcommand\footnote[1]{\kernel@footnote{#1}%
  \@ifnextchar\footnote{\textsuperscript{\,}}{}}
```

However this would break declaring an optional argument to `\footnote` and some more work is needed for this (and would also eat spaces after footnotes).

Happily, Robin Fairbairns has already thought to the problem in his package **footmisc**:

```
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
```

The consecutive footnote marks will be separated by a comma; if you want a thin space, declare

```
\renewcommand{\multfootsep}{\,}
```